# Error with aggregate addFields and not_In in mongdb

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have a collection named **myCollection**, with this data

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e95d26610f6225b09a6dc50"),
    "members" : [ 
        {
            "status" : 4,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e95d26610f6225b09a6dc51"),
            "memberId" : ObjectId("5e95d25f10f6225b09a6dc4f"),
            "date" : ISODate("2020-04-14T15:10:30.914Z")
        }, 
        {
            "status" : 1,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e8c5d0675b1cd342a1175f1"),
            "memberId" : ObjectId("5e7e2f048f80b46d786bfd67"),
            "date" : ISODate("2020-04-07T10:59:18.046Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

i need in my query to use $addFields, with a condition, and i want to exclude some data from members array,

this is my query

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
        {$match: {"_id": ObjectId("5e95d26610f6225b09a6dc50")}},
        {
            $addFields: {
                members: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: "$members",
                        cond: {
                            $and: [
                                { $in: ["$$this.status", [1, 4]]},
                                {$nin : ["$$this._id", [ObjectId("5e7e2f048f80b46d786bfd67"), ObjectId("5e7dbe981ce28a1cef78995a")]]}
                                ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }])
```

I receive this error :

```
MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$nin'
```

How to correct my query using $addFields andd cond, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Because `$nin` is not aggregation pipeline operator you can't use it there.
But you can use `$in` with `$not` operator. So like this

```
...
    $and: [
      { $in: ...}, 
      { $not: { $in: ... } }
    ]
```